# SharePoint - Delete Users from Group in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sharepoint

I have several users that are no longer with our organization that are still in several SharePoint groups. I have the ability to do a mass delete in the SQL database that holds our SharePoint data.

My thought is that a simple DELETE will siffuce:

```
Delete from dbo.GroupMembership where....
```

However, I wanted to know if this is the best way to do this? Is there a better (or safer) way to modify the SharePoint group permissions? Is this a bad way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only table getting affected? You need to check if there are any foreign key references to this table.

Logically a delete should suffice, but it always depends upon you table structure. Need more info.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bad way to do it.

Delete the users from sharepoint using UI or PowerShell.

And Go to the site collection user information list siteurl/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx and delete those users.

Since the users have left the company you also want to disable their AD accounts.